# Authentication Component

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP for the first time. So, please, be patient with me:

I have a table called admin_users, when i try to add the Auth component in my AppController.php.

While executing, I always receive an error telling me that: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_test.users' doesn't exist.
My table is called admin_users, so the error could be because the table should be always called "users" to work properly?

Here is my implementation in AppController.php:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'AdminUsers',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
            $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
```

and in AdminUsersController, the login function:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $adminUser = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($adminUser){
            $this->Auth->setAdminUser($adminUser);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In AppController.php:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->userModel = 'admin_users';
}
```

Comment: The question is about CakePHP 3.x, such configuration is being done via the `config()` method. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers**

Comment: Thank you for you both  but @ndm , you are right!
with config it works, but now i have an error telling me that:
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AdminUsers.username' in 'where clause' . 
Any idea?